# I feel it hard to understand the concept of dimension to an array

Tags: r

[image]

Hello everyone,
I ran a code as below:

```
array(1:12,dim=c(1,3,1,1,2,1,2))
```

And the result was as the screenshot, but I feel it hard to understand
what "dim=c(1,3,1,1,2,1,2)" is doing here, and its relevance to the printout.
Is it possible anyone provides me with some guidance?
Thank you!!!

Comment: It would be better if you could copy/paste the code, rather than posting a screenshot. That is, unless the screenshot conveys information a code dump can't (I don't think that's the case here?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array(1:12,dim=c(1,3,1,1,2,1,2))` creates a 7-dimensional array (there are seven elements in that dimension vector). The length of each dimension is the number you see.
The first dimension has length 1, the second has length 3, and so on.

It might be easier to start with something simpler.

First a matrix (which is a 2-dimensional array)

```
matrix(1:12, nrow=3, ncol=4)

# or
array(1:12, dim=c(3, 4))

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    4    7   10
# [2,]    2    5    8   11
# [3,]    3    6    9   12
```

It should be easy to see what's meant with the 'length' of each dimension here.
It gets a bit more difficult when the array can't be represented as a flat rectangle, but a small 3-dimensional array should still be simple enough to fathom.

```
array(1:24, dim=c(4, 3, 2)

# , , 1

     # [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    5    9
# [2,]    2    6   10
# [3,]    3    7   11
# [4,]    4    8   12

# , , 2

     # [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   13   17   21
# [2,]   14   18   22
# [3,]   15   19   23
# [4,]   16   20   24
```

It's easy to see that rows (1st dimension) is of length 4, columns (2nd dimension) is of length 3, while the third dimension (which doesn't have a commonly accepted proper name) is of length 2.

Extending this to 4, 5, 6… dimension makes it really hard to keep track of how the object would 'look', just as imagining 4, 5, 6… dimensional space is, difficult. We can still quite easily describe things with numbers, however, and perform mathematical operations on these objects.

If your teacher told you to create that object and describe what it represents, I'd say he or she is a little devious. Because, just as a matrix with either the rows or columns at length 1 could in fairness be called a vector (a 1-dimensional object), a 7-dimensional array where four of the dimensions are of length 1, could in fairness be called a 3-dimensional array. Dimensions of length 1 'collapse', as it were.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Sorry for the lack of clarity. I completely understand it now. Thank you for the time and effort!!=)